# Objective guidelines on when to use `Promise` vs `NativeEventEmitter` in react-native bridge

Tags: react-native

React-Native documentation mentions 2 method of sharing the data from native bridge to JS:

- Promise:

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    const eventId = await CalendarModule.createCalendarEvent
  // ...
```

- NativeEventEmitter:

```
let eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.MyBridgeEventEmitter)
eventEmitter.addListener('my event', (something) => { //...
```

But there are no guidelines in documentation when each of them should be used. So beyond some subjective preferences, are there any reasons why one or the other should or shouldn't be used?

More specifically, I am interested in the following situation:

- React-Native requests from native module to launch UI modally. The UI is not just a dialog user will quickly close: user may work on that UI for a while (for example choosing a photo, editing some notes).
- When the user finally closes the native UI, we want to send to React-Native an array. The total size of the array will not exceed about 10K bytes, and for simplicity lets just say all elements in the array are strings.

So is there any *objective* reasons why in this situation either promise or NativeEventEmitter are preferable or should not be used?

My initial thinking is that `NativeEventEmitter` *might* be more preferable in this situation, since

1. opening the UI and receiving the results may be separated in time, and so there's no reason to suspend JS function for potentially a long time, as it may cause some issues?
2. in case of NativeEventEmitter react-native fully owns a lifecycle of the listener of the event, where in case of the promise the bridge will have to hold promise from the moment UI started to its completion, which react-native can't control.

But I am open to changing this opinion if Promise is more advantageous in this case.

Comment: I don't think you'll get objective/definitive answers, but I recommend Promise here.

In general, I use Promises for events that start on the JS side, and NativeEventEmitters for events that don't (like data coming from an IoT device).  

Your dialog starts on the JS side. Using a Promise keeps you from adding event infrastructure for something you have full control over.  Leaving a Promise open doesn't 'suspend' anything on the JS side, it allows the event loop to continue.  The bridge doesn't 'hold' the promise; it invokes the native function and passes the resolve/reject callbacks.

Comment: Thanks @Abe, that's a great input. I am an iOS dev, was asked to assist with RN bridging, so want to make sure my architectural decisions are right...